# Binding expression not supported ColorStateList in android:textColor

Tags: android

I set `textColor` like this

```
android:textColor="@{data.is ? @color/text_color_selector1 : 
 @color/text_color_selector2}"
```

the `color_selector` is :

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" />
 </selector>
```

when I change the textview's status of select, the text color does not change.
I see the color is got from `ViewDataBinding.getColorFromResource` not `ViewDataBinding.getColorStateListFromResource`.

How can i make the generated binding class use the `getColorStateListFromResource` rather than `getColorFromResource`?

Comment: make sure data.is value update or not.

Comment: I have faced the same problem, have you solved the issue?